# Pushkit notification sometimes not received

Tags: ios, pushkit

I'm using pushkit notifications for VOIP application, but sometimes when device is locked I don't receive any notification. Is there something wrong with my implementation or this can happen normally?

EDIT 05.04.2017:

I have found that you will receive VOIP notification only once, while device is in power save mode. It is probably feature from Apple (I have filled ticket, but without any response so far). You can try it nicely on Skype - Lock device, wait 30 minutes, make call, wait 30 minutes, call again and no call is received

Comment: Without any code, it is impossible to tell. However, push notifications are not always delivered as noted by GCM docs and Apple docs. Thus, it is the server's job to retry upon failure. Google's GCM does it automatically, Apple's APNS doesn't. I have no idea about PushKit.

Comment: Well if this is the only way how to do VOIP on iOS, than it is useless. One notification equals one call, so users are not receiving their calls

Comment: @Brandon, VOIP pushes are different to regular pushes. Obviously their delivery can't be guaranteed (how can it if the device is in flight mode for example), but apart them that they are almost guaranteed to be delivered.

Comment: I understand that flight mode is special case, but I have locked ipad on my table and after some random time (minutes to hours) I don't receive any notification. If you I wake up iPad - i receive everything.

Comment: Maleandr, did you ever work out what the problem was? I have a similar problem where push always works with exception of iPhoneX. On iPhoneX, in the app settings, notifications need to be set to "Always", which is not the default setting, and which of course I cannot ask the app user to change. On iPhoneX, with the default setting, the push does not get thought e.g. when the app closed in the background and phone is in lock screen. On all other iPhones my code runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Pushkit integration** - https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

**Swift** - https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification/tree/master/PushDemo

**Objective C** - https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification/tree/master/Objective%20C%20Demo/PushKitDemoObjectiveC

Pushkit notification are lways on high priority, It should reach device.

Possibly while your app is in background or terminated state then somehow at some place your app is getting crashed, So due to this reason pushkit notification reached to device but doesn't work.

Try scheduling local notification on `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload`

You can also test your app in background or terminated state using like below.

**To debug pudhkit delegate in terminated state.**

Put debug pointer on delegate methods, Go to edit scheme, select run option then Launch -> Wait for executable to be launched. Send push kit payload from back end, once you get payload on device, it will automatically invoke and debug pointer will invoke at delegate methods.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but I'm receiving push notifications without problem, when device is not locked. I put a lot of logging to file, so I know iPad is not receiving any notification.